# Return to index, with selected value (Jquery, ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 Project, At my index page, I have a dropdownlist where I want to 'redirect' the selected value back to the same index page.
I wrote a basic function but I have no clue how I can send that selected value with jQuery.

So the situation right now: Every time a user makes the dropdownlist change, the ID of the selected value is*captured in var `selectedFB`.
Then I want a url, link... that passes `selectedFB` back to the index page. But how to generate that URL?

```
<script>
    $(function () {            
        $('#FBType').change(function () {
            var selectedFB = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            var result = '@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", new { id = selectedFB })';
            $("#dynamicLink").attr("href", );
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are mixing client and server site. 2 options for you...

on the client site you need to have your restful route as you use to in MVC like this `http://server/action/parameter`

Or you should build up your client site script dynamic and let the view engine insert the resolved links.

This will not be resolved in the browser
    '@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", new { id = selectedFB })';

Please let me know if this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generate url by @Html.ActionLink on client side.You need something like this.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var action = '@Url.Action("Index", "Index")';   
    $('#FBType').change(function () {
        var selectedFB = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        var result = action + '/' + selectedFB;
        $("#dynamicLink").attr("href", result );
        return true;
    });
});
```